# Change Presence of other contacts

Tags: ucma, lync-2013, lync-server-2010, ucma2.0

is there any way by which we change the presence of other contacts using ApplicationEndPoint, one way which i came across was to create a UserEndpoint and then make presence related changes, but that required credentials to establish UserEndPoint.

Comment: i am now able to change the presence of any sip address by creating a UserEndpoint with AutomaticPresencePublicationEnabled = true in the UserEndpointSettings, but is this the right way ?

Comment: [came across](http://mohamedasakr.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/endpoints-of-ucma-applications/) which says _Application endpoints are not able to perform any contact operations, nor can they publish presence._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot publish presence from an Application Endpoint, you will need to create a UserEndpoint using the SIP uri of the Application Endpoint, and then publish presence using `_userEndPoint.LocalOwnerPresence.BeginPublishPresence()`

Answer (score 1):

Presence is aggregated value, even if you publish extra UserEndPoint it would affect only aggregated value taking in consideration all over published UserEndPoint from the same user. Then what is the meaning of changes in presentity value?